# What can cause a kotlin.TypeCastException for an Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

In the Google Play console, I look at the error report and see the following:

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: 
  at com.app.android.ui.SplashFragment.loadAds (SplashFragment.java:111)
  at com.app.android.ui.SplashFragment$requestConsentInfoUpdate$1.onConsentInfoUpdated (SplashFragment.java:68)
  at com.google.ads.consent.ConsentInformation$ConsentInfoUpdateTask.onPostExecute (ConsentInformation.java:277)
  at com.google.ads.consent.ConsentInformation$ConsentInfoUpdateTask.onPostExecute (ConsentInformation.java:188)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish (AsyncTask.java:632)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600 (AsyncTask.java:177)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage (AsyncTask.java:645)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5942)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1400)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Google also provides additional. error information:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

I tried to run the application on different versions of Android, but I didn’t get an error

The application consists of **one activity (MainActivity)** and several fragments.

**Method in SplashFragment where the error appears:**

```
fun loadAds() {
        (activity as MainActivity).forceShowAd(callback = { // <- вот тут возникает исключение
            Log.i(TAG, "load ads");
            (activity as MainActivity).toMain()
        })
    }
```

**The called method in MainActivity:**

```
fun forceShowAd(callback: () -> Unit) {
        Log.i(TAG, "forceShowAd")
        run {
            val mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
            mInterstitialAd.apply {
                adUnitId = getString(R.string.admob_inter)
                adListener = object : AdListener() {
                    override fun onAdLoaded() {
                        callback()
                        show()
                    }

                    override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: Int) {
                        super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0)
                        var mStartAppAd = StartAppAd(applicationContext)
                        mStartAppAd.loadAd(object : AdEventListener {
                            override fun onReceiveAd(ad: Ad) {
                                mStartAppAd.showAd()
                                callback()
                            }
                            override fun onFailedToReceiveAd(ad: Ad) {
                                callback()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
                loadAd(getAdRequest())
            }
        }

    }
```

**This is how SplashFragment starts in MainActivity:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, SplashFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit()
        }
    }
```

Based on the life cycle of the application, while the fragment is running, activity should also work. But at the same time, as I understand it, at the time the exception was thrown *activity == null*

What could cause the exception problem? **This problem occurs already on 6% of devices**

Answer (score 3):

Your `loadAds()` call appears to be happening as a result of an asynchronous operation (`onConsentInfoUpdated()` being triggered by an `AsyncTask`). You have no idea how long that asynchronous operation will take, and you have no idea what state your activity/fragment might be in at that time. For example, perhaps the user pressed BACK and destroyed `MainActivity` before `loadAds()` got called.

You need to handle the cases where `activity` is `null` or where the activity itself has been destroyed (`isFinishing` or `isDestroyed` are `true`).

Answer (score 0):

In some cases `activity` may be null, for example when user quits it. Without much changes in your code you can handle it using `?` operator:

```
fun loadAds() {
    (activity as? MainActivity)?.forceShowAd(callback = {
        Log.i(TAG, "load ads")
        (activity as? MainActivity)?.toMain()
    })
}
```

Also I would suggest to get rid of `AsyncTask` (it may cause memory leaks and other errors like in your case) and use **Kotlin coroutines**.